# MacOS reusable UI fragments

Tags: xcode, macos

I need reusable UI fragments like this.

[image: reusable UI fragment]

This one particularly consist of a text label, an image and a progress control.
I would like to insert it then in different parts of the application.

For example, on Android declaration and usage of such fragments look like this.

**Declaration:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  style="@style/InfoElementRow">
  <ImageView android:src="@drawable/icon_signal" style="@style/InfoIcon"/>
  <LinearLayout style="@style/InfoElementTextColumn">
    <TextView android:text="Signal:" style="@style/InfoElementDescr"/>
    <ProgressBar
      android:id="@+id/SignalLevel"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"/>
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Usage:**

```
<include layout="@layout/element_SignalLevel"/>
```

What is the **correct way** of doing that on MacOS? Optimally I'd expect the fragment to be declared in a separate xib/storyboard and then reused in other ones with little or no coding.

Comment: Not experienced with Android at all, but from what I understand you are looking for an NSStackView (analogous to LinearLayout) based layout in a custom NSView which will be then instantiated via a xib whenever needed. There are several tutorials (& answers here) for custom view loading from xib files to get you started.

Comment: @Alladinian the concrete placement of the controls is not important. This reusable fragment can be a lot more complex and consisting of several stack panels or other elements, nested in each other.

Comment: Understood... Still, xib based views is what Cocoa offers for reusable UI components.

Comment: @Alladinian  I've seen many such tutorials, but what I didn't like was the necessity of quite a lot of explicit imperative code in all of them. But thanks anyway for your comments.